# Show confirmation prompt when Stop button is clicked

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij IDEA has this stop button, which stops an application:
[image]

The problem I'm having is that usually I run multiple configurations for different parts of application, and when I want to stop just one application, I usually click multiple times this button which closes all running applications.

I know that if I click just once on the button I can select which app I want to stop, but I always forget about it.

Can I configure a prompt like "Are you sure you want to stop [all apps/app xyz]?

Comment: In that popup you can also select that you want to stop all applications. Maybe if you use the shortcut (Ctrl + F2) to stop an application you might not forget about the popup?

Comment: You can remove the button "Stop" from the "Debug" toolbar in "Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Menus and Toolbars | Main Toolbar | Toolbar Run Actions", but keep using the hotkey.